# Is it possible to auto generate some code in HTML?

Tags: html, survey

I'm a newbie with HTML and maybe the question is very stupid but Is it possible to create a loop in html?

What I have done so far is a survey that asks the user a number. Now with that number the idea is to create a determined text area with some inputs.

This is what I have:

```
<p>-----DEFINITIONS----- 

    <h1 id="demo"></h1>
    <script>
        var cant_def=prompt("How many definitions do you have?")
        var cant_par= prompt("How many pairs do you have?")

    </script>
    <p><b>Definition 1:</b></p>
    <p>Introduce the word:</p>
    <input type="text" name="campo1" style="width: 300px;"/>
    <p>Introduce the meaning:</p>
    <input type="text" name="camp1_res" style="width: 500px;" />

   <!--<textarea id="def1" rows="1" cols="20" name="def1"></textarea></p>  --> 
</p>
```

The area named "Definition 1:" only will works if the given number saved in "cant_def" is 1 and "cant_par" is 2. But if you want to have 3 definitions and 4 pairs the group "Definition 1" will appear 3 times with "campo1" and "camp1_res" repeated 4 times.

Let me show you what I mean with a graphic example.

The webpage asks you for the numbers and you write "2" and then, "2". So this would be the code generated:

```
<p><b>Definition 1:</b></p>
    <p>Introduce the word:</p>
    <input type="text" name="campo1" style="width: 300px;"/>
    <p>Introduce the meaning:</p>
    <input type="text" name="camp1_res" style="width: 500px;" />
    <p>Introduce the word:</p>
    <input type="text" name="campo1" style="width: 300px;"/>
    <p>Introduce the meaning:</p>
    <input type="text" name="camp1_res" style="width: 500px;" />



    <p><b>Definition 2:</b></p>
    <p>Introduce the word:</p>
    <input type="text" name="campo1" style="width: 300px;"/>
    <p>Introduce the meaning:</p>
    <input type="text" name="camp1_res" style="width: 500px;" />
    <p>Introduce the word:</p>
    <input type="text" name="campo1" style="width: 300px;"/>
    <p>Introduce the meaning:</p>
    <input type="text" name="camp1_res" style="width: 500px;" />
```

And this would be the result:

[image]

Another important thing, the variable "cant_par" must be an even number!
Thanks in advise~

Comment: HTML is not a programming language and, therefore, cannot create programming constructs. HTML is for document structure, not programming.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents

Answer (score -2):

HTML is only a markup language, and cannot actually execute code. However, you can use JavaScript to loop using a `for` and/or `while` setup.

```js
var number_of_definitions = 5;
for(i=0;i!=number_of_definitions;i++) {
    document.write("your html here");
}
```

Also, your definitions should be places in `<div>` elements for easier handling. They help a lot when you get to CSS or when trying and format anything.

Comment: Hey there, welcome to SO! Just wanted to point out to you why you are probably getting downvoted. You did not declare your `i` value with `let` or `var` so it is an implicit global variable. Big no-no. You also used `!=` when you should always prefer `!==`. Then you use `document.write` which should always be avoided, **especially** from inside a loop. DOM operations are very expensive and should be limited as much as possible. Better than the HTML elements or strings are formed within the loop and then inserted into the DOM just once at the end of the loop.